# How to grow Labels within a VBox

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I got the following setup:

```
Label errorLabel = new Label("Hello Hans");
Label warningLabel = new Label("HEEELLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
VBox box = new VBox();
box.getChildren().addAll(errorLabel, warningLabel);
Tooltip t = new Tooltip();
t.setGraphic(box);
t.show();
```

My problem is, that `warningLabel` and `errorLabel` have different sizes. They should both grow to the same size horizontally. I don't want to put a specific size. The size of both must be whichever label needs more to display the whole text.

The problem is, that both Labels have a background and you can see that the warningLabel takes more space. I need both backgrounds of those label grow equally.

Comment: Normally `Label`s will grow based on their content, so I don't understand what is the question. Could you please specify it more precisely? For example a sample text for both `Label` and a picture what you got and what would you like to got.

Comment: @DVarga: Thanks. I cannot provide screenshots since the PC I'm working on is strictly disconnected from the internet and I can't share anything between the PC I'm writing this and the PC I'm working on. I added some details though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [maxWidthProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#maxWidthProperty) to `Double.MAX_VALUE` in case of both `Label`s.

```
Label errorLabel = new Label("Hello Hans");
errorLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
Label warningLabel = new Label("HEEELLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
warningLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange");
warningLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
errorLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

*The output `Tooltip` is like:*

[image]

Background: [Making Buttons the Same Size - Using a VBox - Example 2-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/size_align.htm)

> To enable all of the buttons to be resized to the width of the VBox
>   pane, the maximum width of each button is set to the Double.MAX_VALUE
>   constant, which enables a control to grow without limit. An
>   alternative to using the maximum value constant is to set the maximum
>   width to a specific value, such as 80.0.

**Note:** Important that the [fillWidthProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#fillWidthProperty) of the `VBox` must be set to `true` (this property is `true` by default):

> Whether or not resizable children will be resized to fill the full
>   width of the vbox or be kept to their preferred width and aligned
>   according to the alignment hpos value.

This is important because:

> VBox will resize children (if resizable) to their preferred heights
>   and uses its fillWidth property to determine whether to resize their
>   widths to fill its own width or keep their widths to their preferred
>   (fillWidth defaults to true).

So, if the `fillWidthProperty` is set to true, the `VBox` will try to resize its children to its own width, which is impossible if the `maxWidthProperty` is set to the preferred width of each children, that's why this property must be set to a "big-enough" number.

Comment: This is it... Thank you very much! It looks like a hack to me, that you need to put a "high" Double value as maxWidth to achieve this, but this did the job! :)

Comment: I have updated the answer to convince you it is not a hack, and what's the logic behind :)

Comment: I forgot to accept and vote, sry. I didn't want to tell you that you put up a hack here, but that it feels a bit strange that this needs to be achieved on such a way. The `maxWidthProperty`, for instance, could be set by default to Double.`MAX_VALUE`.